# TSQL Trigger with INSTEAD OF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

So I am trying to build a  simple trigger that will cause an error message to popup if a credit card date entered has passed. If the cards date is still good, I would like it to update or insert as usual. I am still very new to dealing with SQL Server and trying to wrap my head around the contexts of how things should be setup correctly. I have a feeling I am way off on setting this up correctly but any advice would be kindly appreciated.

The Table contains, (CreditCardID (PK), CardType, CardNumber, ExpMonth, ExpYear, ModifiedDate

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE TRIGGER BadCreditCardDate
ON Sales.CreditCard
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
AS
Begin
DECLARE @ExpMonth tinyint,
        @ExpYear smallint


SELECT @ExpMonth=ExpMonth, @ExpYear=ExpYear
FROM INSERTED

IF
    @ExpMonth < MONTH(GETDATE())
    AND 
    @ExpYear < YEAR(GETDATE())
RAISERROR ('The Credit Card you have entered has expired.' ,10,1)

ELSE    
DECLARE @CreditCardID INT
INSERT INTO CreditCard (CardType, CardNumber, ExpMonth, ExpYear, ModifiedDate)

Select CardType, CardNumber, ExpMonth, ExpYear, ModifiedDate FROM inserted
WHERE CreditCardID = @CreditCardID
```

END

Comment: The CreditCardID variable is never assigned so your where clause in your else condition will never find a record (null != anything). While I don't think it's a big deal, one other option rather than using an INSTEAD OF trigger is to use a FOR trigger, check your conditions and if they fail, roll back the current transaction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `ELSE` condition only apply to the next statement which is `DECLARE @CreditCardID INT`. You should use `BEGIN/END` around your entire `ELSE` block.

Second, the logic in this trigger will fail if you decide to update multiple rows since it is only considering one row updates. This may happen if you need to import customer data from another source.

Third. You should handle UPDATES and INSERTS separately. I would probably consider creating 2 triggers, one for update, another for insert, just to avoid costly determination of what happened and a lot of if and else logic.